# Rails, jQuery, .js.erb files, JS not executed by the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to use jQuery, and everything has been great, until now, when I'm trying to render a partial and append it to a div. Here is how I have it set up:

I have an action that responds to js:

```
def index
  @objects = Object.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And a template called index.js.erb with some javascript in it:

```
alert("hello world");
```

Firebug returns a "text/javascript" response containing:

```
alert("hello world");
```

But the alert window does not appear, nor does any other JavaScript work. I checked out http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery
And am more or less following along. I tried several other things, like using .rjs instead of .erb and putting this in my template:

```
page.alert("hello world");
```

but I get the same exact result, and the browser never executes the JS.

Anyone know why the JavaScript isn't being executed?

I'm running Rails 2.3.4.

Comment: You don't appear to be using anything jQuery specific, but just as a note, Rails ships with Prototype, not jQuery. Check out jRails if you want to switch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to call it from your view or it will never be executed.

an example controller:

```
def index
  @objects = Object.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{
      render :text => "alert('hello')"
    }
  end
end
```

and an index.html.erb with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: '/controller', type: 'get', dataType:'script' });
  });
</script>
```

replace '/controller' with the actual url that executes that controller's index action, by default for PostsController it will be '/posts' and so on...

if you like rjs you delete the {} and everithing in it in the controller and create an index.js.erb or index.rjs with:

```
page.alert("hello world")
```

or:

```
page << "hello world"
```

Comment: I my situation, I don't have an html version of this action, its strictly for loading pages via ajax (endless pagination).

For some reason, even when I call render :text => "alert('hello');" in my respond_to block, I still don't get alerted, but firebug says I'm getting a text/javascript response with the correct content.

Comment: Well. turns out I forgot dataType : 'script' in my ajax call. Thanks for your help, wouldn't have caught that one on my own.

Comment: dataType: 'script' also saved me when using the jQuery Form Plugin.  Once you get the js.erb set up correctly, it still won't run as JavaScript without it.  Thanks!